# Huge APK size with Mozilla Android Components

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, apk, mozilla

I'm building an APK (not app bundle) using Gradle via Android Studio.
Without adding any Mozilla dependencies in my app's build.gradle file the APK size is under 5MB but after adding these dependencies the APK size increases to over 100MB.

Most of the APK size is in the (new) lib directory, particularly the lib/libxul.so file, but also the assets/omni.ja file is around 9MB.

I am aware of how to reduce the APK size by using ABI filters and APK splitting to generate separate APKs for different architectures, but this can only do so much to reduce the download size for the user. Is there any way I can significantly reduce the size of my APK? Are there any command line options I can add or additional Gradle options to achieve this?

For reference, I am importing the following dependencies: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components

from here: https://maven.mozilla.org/maven2

Answer (score 0):

The official recommendation is here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.

And you can also use Play feature delivery to serve some features only when needed by users: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/play-feature-delivery